# How to cut a Numpy 2d array and store as a 3d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

suppose I have the following Numpy 2d array (3*9)

```
[[-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2]
 [-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2]
 [-2 -2 71 -1 -1 -1 71 -1 52]]
```

I would like to equally divide this whole array by 3 and get the target array like this, which means I should get a 3d array of shape(3 by 3 by3):

```
[[-2 -2 -2] [-2 -2 -2] [-2 -2 -2]
 [-2 -2 -2] [-2 -2 -2] [-2 -2 -2]
 [-2 -2 71] [-1 -1 -1] [71 -1 52]]
```

Anyone can explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the previous shape and target shape, you can simply use `reshape`

```
arr = [[-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
[-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,],
[-2, -2, 71, -1, -1, -1, 71, -1, 52]]
arr = np.array(arr)
arr.reshape(3,3,3)
```

Comment: Note that you could let numpy do the calculation for you: `arr.reshape(3,-1,3)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reshape` method like the following

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],
                [-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],
                [-2,-2,71,-1,-1,-1,71,-1,52]])

newarr = array.reshape(3,3,3)
print(newarr)
```